# What causes a ++ value to go backwards?

Tags: android, loops, integer, while-loop

So I have a while loop that is being triggered, and for naming I am using an additional value.

totalPlayerCount can be either 1,2,3 or 4 and whatever I choose for that seems to automatically set nameLoop that value.. regardless of nameLoop = 1;

To top it off, I have nameLoop++; as the bottom and when it starts it says Player 4, then Player 3, then Player 2, then Player 1...

Why on earth would it be going backwards?  Theres only 3 instances of nameLoop in the whole file so its not being affected anywhere else.

```
public void setNames() {
    int nameLoop = 1;
    while (totalPlayerCount >= 1){          

    //**********************//
    //***SET PLAYER NAMES***//
    //**********************//
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Player " + nameLoop);
    alert.setMessage("Name:");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      name = input.getText().toString();
      // Do something with value!
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
    totalPlayerCount--;
    nameLoop++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are counting down the number of players while iterating through them. Try changing it to:

```
int nameLoop = totalPlayerCount; //the 2nd line of your code
...
totalPlayerCount--; //the bottom few lines of your code
nameLoop--;
```

This should fix it, but the part you *really* need to change is where ever you are using `nameLoop` to assign player number.

Comment: You see, it wasn't counting backwards, you are looping through them backwards (or assigning their names backwards).

Comment: I got ya, that did the trick.. Is there a way to prevent all 4 from being created at once?  and have it create 1, complete and loop again, create and loop again.. etc.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that it makes them in the right order, but 4 is made last so it appears on top of 3, which is on top of 2, which is on top of 1?

EDIT:  How about something like

```
private int nameLoop = 1; // make nameLoop a data member

public void setNames(int nameLoop) {
    if(nameLoop<totalPlayerCount) {
        //Build and show dialog here
        public void onClick(... ...) {
            nameLoop++
            setNames(nameLoop);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

It's just off the top of my head and not tested!

Comment: I think that might be it.  Looks like i need to figure out how to make it only happen 1 at a time.